# Table of contents for preview epub Book

Tags: preview, epub, tableofcontents

I would like to make a preview/extract of my e-book epub. 
The extract contains only two chapters, but I want to have a table of contents which includes all chapters. The unincluded chapters should not be shown as links. Just text headline. How can I do that?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about in your toc.xhtml, all you need to do is remove the `<a>...</a>` tags from around the items in question. If you're talking about in the toc.ncx, there isn't really a way to show items that don't exist in there. You could approximate that by including a final page in the extract that talks about where to get the full version, or about the author, or anything else, and put something like `<span id="chapter3" /> <span id="chapter4" />` and so on on that page. That would give the Table of Contents links something to point to, and would get your readers to some potentially useful information.

Answer (score 0):

in the `ncx` you should be able to get away with replacing the `src` attribute in the content tags with `#`, but i doubt it will validate

```xml
<navPoint id="navPoint-1" playOrder="1">
  <navLabel>
    <text>ch 1</text>
  </navLabel>
  <content src="Text/Section0001.xhtml" />
</navPoint>
<navPoint id="navPoint-2" playOrder="2">
  <navLabel>
    <text>ch 2</text>
  </navLabel>
  <content src="#" />
</navPoint>
<navPoint id="navPoint-3" playOrder="3">
  <navLabel>
    <text>ch 3</text>
  </navLabel>
  <content src="#" />
</navPoint>
```